# Qt WebEngine for 32Bit windows

Tags: qtwebengine

I wrote an application using `Qt WebEngine` with `Qt5.11.1` .
A moment ago I noticed this line in Maintain Application of Qt:

> On Windows, the module is only available under MSVC 2017 64bit.

i need to compile this for x86 (32bit) systems.
which version of qt has Qt webEngine with 32bit support?

In maintenance application for versions between 5.9.7 and 5.10.1 this line does not exist?
could it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`5.10.1` works with 32bit platform